# JavaFX With Scene builder Controller Error About addAll?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error while using JavaFX with Scene Builder. I didn't understand why I'm getting the error.
There is a problem with method `addAll()`, I think.

```
public class FXML_PatientListController implements Initializable {
    private Room rr=null;

    @FXML
    private TextArea p_id;
    @FXML
    private TextArea p_name;
    @FXML
    private TextArea sk;
    @FXML
    private Button enter;
    @FXML
    private Button delete;
    @FXML
    private TableView<?> list;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> p_id_T;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> p_name_T;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> Sk_T;

    @FXML
    private void close (ActionEvent av){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    public void setPatientInfo(Room r) {
        rr = r;
        showPatients(null);
    }

    public void showPatients(Event s) {
        list.getItems().clear();
        if (rr != null) {
            list.getItems().addAll(rr.getPatient()); // I get a error here.
        }
    }
```

And the error:

```
no suitable method found for addAll(ArrayList<Patient>) method List.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Patient> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#1>) method ObservableList.addAll(CAP#1...) is not applicable (varargs mismatch; ArrayList<Patient> cannot be converted to CAP#1) where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? ---- (Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I got this project from object oriented class.

Comment: You need to replace the wildcard type parameters. Instead of `TableView<?> list` write `TableView<Patient> list`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few more things to handle before you can add your data. You need to type assign your columns the Patient class and each fields type. Some sudo code below...

```
@FXML
private TableView<Patient> tbl;
@FXML
private TableColumn< Patient, String> patientName;

private final ObservableList< Patient > tblData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    setPatientName(patientName);
    tbl.setItems(tblData);
}

/**
* Use this method to set the column properties. You should of course make this generic but just by way of an example...
*/
public static void setPatientName(TableColumn< Patient, String> column) {
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("patientName"));
    column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
}
```